# pre-git's pre-commit hook is not waiting for the task to complete

Tags: node.js, npm, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Our pre-git configuration in package.json looks like

```
"pre-git": {
      "pre-commit": [
        "npm run lint",
        "npm run coverage",
        "npm run coverage-check"
      ],
      "post-commit": [
        "git status"
      ]
    }
```

But, the "pre-commit" hook is not waiting for "npm run coverage" to complete (which is an **istanbul cover** task). **npm run coverage** runs fine individually. Are we missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using "npm run" ... Just list the tools by them aliases available on scripts section. This is the way I worked with NodeJS. "pre-git" is new to me. I used directly a package called "pre-commit" which worked fine the way I just described.

Then, for a more generic solution, I wrote this tool:

https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git/

Comment: This is the npm package I used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit

Comment: I need both of them, pre-commit and post-commit, thanks a lot for the pointers!